# How To Clear LiveBindings In Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, livebindings

While experimenting with LiveBindings with Delphi XE4 I selected BindVisually from the object inspector.  How do you clear or eliminate the LiveBindings?

```
Object Inspector
TForm1
Property
LiveBindings:  LiveBindings
```

If I try to remove the LiveBindings by editing at Design time it can not be removed.
If I open the bindings viewer no bondings have been set.
There is no provision to clear the livebings in the designer or in the object inspector.

Answer (score 1):

The Live Bindings property is supposed to be there in the object inspector since it's a published property of the component, you cannot remove it. Every component that can be binded has that property.

Comment: I did not did not do any binding, but you can not delete 'LiveBindings" in the object inspector?  It will not let me set it to blank.

Comment: I guess I did not understand this... Livebindings is already set even in a new blank vcl form project.  So it looks like what I am seeing is just normal... so I withdraw my question.

Comment: @BIll, what you are seeing in the object inspector is completely normal. The Live Bindings property is supposed to be there, you cannot remove it.